# Convenience initialiser of CIFilter is giving strange exception

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

Here is the code I am trying,

```
typealias Parameters = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

extension CIFilter {
    convenience init(name: String, parameters: Parameters) {
        self.init(name: "CIGloom")
        setDefaults()
        for (key, value: AnyObject) in parameters {
            setValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    var outPutImage: CIImage {
        return self.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as CIImage
    }
}
```

The exception is occurring during `self.init(name: "CIGloom")`, I tried different filter name but the result is same.

```
2014-11-11 15:08:27.866 HelloCIFilter[15217:451450] +[NSObject customAttributes]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10e26fd28
```