# Swift convenience init crashes

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

Here is the code I have in a **playground**

```
import UIKit
extension CIFilter {
    convenience init(name: String, dummy: String) {
        self.init(name: name)
    }
}
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", dummy: "dummy")
```

It crashes (exception) with XCode 6.1 on the line `self.init. ([NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:])`

It also crashes in an application context instead of a playground !
Any idea ?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862019/convenience-initialiser-of-cifilter-is-giving-strange-exception .